# Fix Issue of installing "pydot"

Tags: python, installation, pydot

I tried to install the pydot package with following command,

`sudo pip install pydot`

After that, I tried to test whether it's successfully installed, but encountered  following error.

```
import pydot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydot.py", line 22, in <module>
    __version__ = '1.0.%d' % int( __revision__[21:-2] )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

How could I fix this issue?

BTW, I have successfully installed `graphviz` package, as a prerequisite. And my python version is 2.7.6.

Comment: This is a bug - https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pip install pydot2`? it work on me.