# pydot installation with pip3 issue

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pydot

I am trying to install pydot.  I get the following interaction:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pydot
Collecting pydot
  Using cached pydot-1.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ykyu42cx/pydot/setup.py", line 5
        except ImportError, excp:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ykyu42cx/pydot
```

I am however successful when I try:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pydot2
```

I doubt this is the desired behavior.

Please advise if possible on how to use pip3 to install pydot.

Comment: PS:  I have already consulted,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158889/fix-issue-of-installing-pydot

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions for python3

```
pip install pydot3
```

or

```
pip install pydotplus
```